# Spring boot Controller is not able to find the bean class

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

---

I am new at Spring and i am tring to built a simple registration form using spring boot and storing user information in mysql database using jpa.

**This is my error stack.**

```
----------


  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.5.3.RELEASE)

2017-06-05 12:34:53.392  INFO 9128 --- [           main] com.mohit.LoanapimainApplication         : Starting LoanapimainApplication on MOHIT with PID 9128 (C:\Users\admin\Documents\workspace-sts-3.8.4.RELEASE\loanapimain\target\classes started by admin in C:\Users\admin\Documents\workspace-sts-3.8.4.RELEASE\loanapimain)
2017-06-05 12:34:53.407  INFO 9128 --- [           main] com.mohit.LoanapimainApplication         : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2017-06-05 12:34:53.815  INFO 9128 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@396c1e: startup date [Mon Jun 05 12:34:53 IST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-06-05 12:34:55.754  INFO 9128 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2017-06-05 12:34:55.772  INFO 9128 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service Tomcat
2017-06-05 12:34:55.772  INFO 9128 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.14
2017-06-05 12:34:56.006  INFO 9128 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2017-06-05 12:34:56.006  INFO 9128 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2207 ms
2017-06-05 12:34:56.163  INFO 9128 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2017-06-05 12:34:56.163  INFO 9128 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2017-06-05 12:34:56.163  INFO 9128 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2017-06-05 12:34:56.163  INFO 9128 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2017-06-05 12:34:56.163  INFO 9128 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2017-06-05 12:34:56.756  INFO 9128 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2017-06-05 12:34:56.771  INFO 9128 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
2017-06-05 12:34:56.881  INFO 9128 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.0.12.Final}
2017-06-05 12:34:56.881  INFO 9128 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2017-06-05 12:34:56.881  INFO 9128 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
2017-06-05 12:34:56.927  INFO 9128 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
2017-06-05 12:34:57.052  INFO 9128 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
2017-06-05 12:34:57.615  INFO 9128 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2017-06-05 12:34:57.631  WARN 9128 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'user'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.mohit.beans.User' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
2017-06-05 12:34:57.631  INFO 9128 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2017-06-05 12:34:57.631  INFO 9128 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service Tomcat
2017-06-05 12:34:57.646  INFO 9128 --- [           main] utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2017-06-05 12:34:57.740 ERROR 9128 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field user in com.mohit.Controllers.UserController required a bean of type 'com.mohit.beans.User' that could not be found.
```

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.mohit.beans.User' in your configuration.

---

**Contoller**`

```
package com.mohit.Controllers;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import com.mohit.beans.User;

import com.mohit.Services.createuser;

@Controller
public class UserController {


    @Autowired(required=true)
    private User user;
    @Autowired(required=true)
    private createuser create;

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String sayhi(){


        return "index";

    }

    @RequestMapping("/index")
    public String Createuser(@RequestParam(value="uname") String name,@RequestParam(value="pass") String pass, Model model){
        user.setUname(name);
        user.setPass(pass);
        create.adduser(user);
        return "result";

    }

    public String AuthUser(@RequestParam(value="name") String name,@RequestParam(value="pass") String pass, Model model){


        return "mainpage";

    }



}



----------
```

### **bean class**

```
 --------------



----------

    package com.mohit.beans;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    private String uname;
    private String pass;
    public User(String uname, String pass) {
        super();

        this.uname = uname;
        this.pass = pass;
    }


    public User() {
        super();
    }


    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }


    public String getUname() {
        return uname;
    }
    public void setUname(String uname) {
        this.uname = uname;
    }
    public String getPass() {
        return pass;
    }
    public void setPass(String pass) {
        this.pass = pass;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User [id=" + id + ", uname=" + uname + ", pass=" + pass + "]";
    }


}



----------
```

### **Service class**

```
----------
package com.mohit.Services;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.mohit.Repo.userrepo;
import com.mohit.beans.User;

@Service
public class createuser {

    @Autowired
    private userrepo Userrepo;

    public void adduser(User user)
    {
        Userrepo.save(user);
    }


}




----------
```

### **Repository**

```
--------------



----------

    package com.mohit.Repo;
import org.springframework.data.repository.PagingAndSortingRepository;
import com.mohit.beans.User;


public interface userrepo extends PagingAndSortingRepository<User,String> {

}


----------
```

## **pom.xml**`

```
----------


?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.mohit</groupId>
    <artifactId>loanapimain</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>loanapimain</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>


----------
```

### **Application.config**

```
    spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/project
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver


----------
```

### **LoanapiApplication.java**`

```
package com.mohit;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class LoanapimainApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(LoanapimainApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: you want to fo crud operations on the db right from spring boot why dnt you use sprind data jpa , JPA repository

Comment: @Rahul I am using spring JPA only in my project. Thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`User` is not a bean but Entity - simple POJO class. It can't be autowired.

Change the logic to

```
@RequestMapping("/index")
public String Createuser(@RequestParam(value="uname") String name,@RequestParam(value="pass") String pass, Model model){
    User user = new User();
    user.setUname(name);
    user.setPass(pass);
    create.adduser(user);
    return "result";

}
```

and remove the User field from the controller